# discord.js removing roles of member who deletes more than one channel recently

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm kind of new to bot coding so I would like to get some help on this,

So, I wanted my bot to remove all permissions of a member which intends to delete more than 1 channel in 2 minutes interval. I made something like this below;

```js
       client.on("channelDelete", async function(channel) {

    const channelDeleteId = channel.id;

    // finding all channel deletions in the log
    channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
            'type': 'CHANNEL_DELETE'
        })
        // finding the log entry for this specific channel
        .then(logs => logs.entries.find(entry => entry.target.id === channelDeleteId))
        .then(entry => {
            // getting the author of the deletion
            author = entry.executor;

            if (author.id === "472911936951156740") return console.log("VoiceMaster Bot has deleted a channel."); // dont mind, it's ok

            console.log(`channel ${channel.name} deleted by ${author}`);

            let member = channel.guild.members.cache.find(m => m.id === author.id);
            let deletedRecently = new Set;


            if (deletedRecently.has(member)) {

                member.roles.set([]);
                //member.ban();

            } else {
                deletedRecently.add(member);
                setTimeout(() => {

                    deletedRecently.delete(member);

                }, 120000);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
});
```

When I test it, it sometimes loops 3-4 times and triggers the role removing row.

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? What is your problem with the code you have written? How did you expected it to work and how does it work?

Comment: I wanted my bot to remove all permissions of a member which intends to delete more than 1 channel in 2 minutes interval. Its purpose is to block the intruder and malicious action maker. So when I delete a channel, sometimes this channelDelete event triggers more than once and fills my deletedRecently condition before the deletedchannelcount 2 

I want this to do 

[intruder deletes a channel]
bot takes his ID to memory (else block)
[intruder deletes another channel in 2mins]
bot takes all of his roles (if block)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thx. It was all about my little mistake. Sry for bothering...

Comment: It's helpful to post the solution in case someone has the same issue.